# before editing table view,do not detect willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath and didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone

I have defined a UITableview object,setEditing:YES,override function canEditRowAtIndexPath:,it return YES.
So it can edit well,delete or insert.Through commitEditingStyle:.But when before editing，it do not dect functions that willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath and didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath defined.The two function could not be called.
why??

thanks.

Comment: Sorry to say this... just cannot make out what exactly you are asking.

Answer (score -1):

when click the "delete" button,willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath don't be called automatically.precondition I have defined the "editing" property.

Comment: I don't quite understand your answer. Can you elaborate?